# Getting Linux network stats in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm tasked with helping gather network data from Linux machines in C++. I'm new to C++, and need some advice. I need to take this shell script and simulate it as close as possible. Basically, I need to dump all the networking details of the machine - netstat or ss, ifconfig, etc.

Previous shell script snippet:

```
get_networkdata(){
    #All Active Network Connections
    {
        if netstat -pvWanoee &> /dev/null
        then
            # gnu
            netstat -pvWanoee
        elif netstat -pvTanoee &> /dev/null
    then
            # redhat/centos
            netstat -pvTanoee
    else
        netstat -anp
        fi
    } > "$SAVETO/netstat.txt"

    #Network Configuration
    {
        echo  -e "\n</etc/network/interfaces>";cat /etc/network/interfaces
        echo  -e "\n<ifconfig -a>";ifconfig -a
        echo  -e "\n</etc/resolv.conf>";cat /etc/resolv.conf
        echo  -e "\n<ip addr>"; ip addr
        echo  -e "\n<ip link>";ip link
        echo  -e "\n<netstat -anp>;"netstat -anp
        if lsof -i -n -P &> /dev/null
        then
            echo  -e "\n<lsof -i -n -P>";lsof -i -n -P
        fi
        echo  -e "\n<ss -ap>";ss -ap
        echo  -e "\n<route -n>";route -n # "netstat -nr"; "ip route"
        echo  -e "\n<ip neigh>";ip neigh
        echo  -e "\n</etc/hostname>";cat /etc/hostname
        echo  -e "\n<cat /etc/hosts>";cat /etc/hosts
        echo  -e "\n<cat /etc/hosts.allow>";cat /etc/hosts.allow
        echo  -e "\n<cat /etc/hosts.deny>";cat /etc/hosts.deny
    } > "$SAVETO/netinfo.txt"

    #SSH Folder Copy
    tar -zcvf "$SAVETO/ssh_folder.tar.gz" /etc/ssh/* 2> /dev/null
}
```

And this is what I've tried in C++ so far. It works, in creating the text files, but I feel like I'm shortcutting or not doing it efficiently. Any advice is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string GetStdoutfromCommand(string cmd) {

        string data;
        FILE * stream;
        const int max_buffer = 256;
        char buffer[max_buffer];
        cmd.append (" 2>&1" );

        stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
        if (stream) {

            while (!feof(stream))
            if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) !=nullptr) data.append(buffer);
            pclose(stream);
        }

        return data;
    }

    int main () {

        string net_devices = GetStdoutfromCommand("ifconfig -a >network_devices.txt");
        string ss = GetStdoutfromCommand("ss -a -pl >netstats.txt");
        string ip_route = GetStdoutfromCommand("ip route >ip_route.txt");

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use three important facts: 1) that Linux is open source, 2) most of it and its system calls are written in C, and 3) C can compile as C++.

So if you take for example your code above, if you want to do ifconfig more efficiently, start with what you have, and then replace the ifconfig code with parts of the original source which can be found here:

https://github.com/giftnuss/net-tools/blob/master/ifconfig.c

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the /proc file system.
However beware that it changes from Linux version to version.